# Method Skipped,when run with testng TEST annotation.How to provide parameters? I went to testng documentation but couldn't understand, please guide

Tags: testng

**Code**:

```
package tests;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
public class SearchText {


    public void createzoo(String[] args) {  

        String[] elems = {"lion", "tiger", "duck"};  
        System.out.println(elems[0]);
        System.out.println(elems[1]);
        System.out.println(elems[2]);
    }
}
```

Results:

> SKIPPED: createzoo org.testng.TestNGException:  Method createzoo
>   requires 1 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Test annotation.

Comment: What exactly did u not understand? The documentation does provide samples..did u try. Those out?

Answer (score 4):

The example createzoo method is not actually using the args passed in.
Since it is not using them, just change the message signature to:

```
public void createzoo()
```

Most JUnit/TestNG tests do not take any arguments.
You may be confusing it with the typical program that has a public static void main(String[] args)

Tests don't have a `main()` per se and the framework will run your tests for you.

Only use the parameters mentioned by others if you really need them and the method is going to do something with them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the value for the parameter `String[] args` in the `createzoo` method. Here are several ways to do it:

- Use [@Parameters](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-testng-xml) annotation on the method and supply values in testng.xml file.
- [Dataprovider](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) (also mentioned by Cedric in his response).
- Put [@Optional](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/Optional.html) annotation on your parameter and supply default value.

Read TestNG documentation - it has a lot of examples on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant documentation:  http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders

Comment: Hi Cedric, I have an unrelated question about testng. Please help me. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839614/how-is-this-alternative-to-testng-softassert